# How to better use STLs and functors for getting solution for sliding window minimum

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, stl-algorithm

> Learning stls and c++11

Was working through some of example and here is one which targets to get minimum for each sliding window for a given sequence.

Given below is my solution which I did in a very naive way, but it could definitely be improved by using stls, algorithms or any other c++11 feature.

I am not looking for complete code (but anyone interest could do that), instead for some advises which would help me

```
1. identify if `std::copy_if` or `back_inserter` could be used to construct result
2. if `std::transform` is the way to get the job done instead of `while's`
3. or any c++11 features would allow me to simplify more and exception safe program
```

I know it is kind of asking as kid for c++, but that is what I am now :-)

> My Solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

/*
*  get minimum for each sliding window of size w
*
*  a = {1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7};
*  w = 3
*  r = {-1, -3, -3, -3, 3, 3}
*/

void GetMinLookUpForWindow(const std::vector<int> &src, std::vector<int> &res, const size_t w) {

    std::deque<size_t> priority;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i) {

        // initialization phase and push min for first window w
        if (!priority.empty() &&
            src[i] < src[priority.back()]) {
            priority.pop_back();
        }
        priority.push_back(i);
    }

    //iterate through rest of values and maintain min @front in deque
    for (int i = w; i < src.size(); ++i) {

        // required min element is at front ...
        res.push_back(src[priority.front()]);

        // pop all max from back
        while (!priority.empty() &&
            src[i] < src[priority.back()]) {
            priority.pop_back();
        }

        // pop all front till index out of current window
        while (!priority.empty() && priority.front() <= i - w) {
            priority.pop_front();
        }

        //  offer the current index
        priority.push_back(i);
    }

    // get the final element for last window
    res.push_back(src[priority.front()]);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec({ 1, 3, -1, -3, 5, 3, 6, 7 });
    size_t w = 3;

    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> res;

    GetMinLookUpForWindow(vec, res, w);

    std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Regards,

> Solution by combining both answers

***Modified function:***

```
void GetMinLookUpForWindowModified( std::pair<std::vector<int>::const_iterator, std::vector<int>::const_iterator> range,
                                    std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int>> op,
                                    size_t w) {

    for (auto it = range.first; it < range.second - w + 1; ++it, ++op) {
        auto it_min = std::min_element(it, it + w);
        op = *it_min;
    }
}
```

***Callee code:***

```
GetMinLookUpForWindowModified(make_pair(vec.begin(), vec.end()), std::back_inserter(res), w);
```

Comment: Note there is already a StackExchange site for code reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you mention in your prelude, I would pass GetMinLookUpForWindow a pair of iterators for range and an output iterator.

Thinking in terms of iterators and algorithms is one of those little leaps that make your code more readable and maintainable.

Even if you didn't go this route you should use iterators for loops inside your function.

The first section where you initially prime the queue is needlessly complex. You should just be able to fire either all `w` items at it regardless or miss out that step entirely.

Also `priority_queue` should maintain your queue to a comparator, which will sort it for you which is seemingly what you will end up with.

Comment: thanks for giving directions I have used your's and mikes example to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple possibilities. The simplest one I can think of (and without changing the interface) would be this:

```
void GetMinLookUpForWindow(const std::vector<int> &src, std::vector<int> &res, const size_t w) {
    for (auto it = src.begin(); it < src.end() - w +1; ++it) {
        res.push_back(*std::min_element(it, it +w));            
    }   
}
```

For longer windows, you can tweak it a little, by remembering the last minimum position (you would have to measure, if this is really faster):

```
template<class IT>
IT minIterator(IT l, IT r) {
    return *l < *r ? l : r;
}

void GetMinLookUpForWindow(const std::vector<int> &src, std::vector<int> &res, const size_t w) {
    auto it_min = std::min_element(src.begin(), src.begin() + w);   
    for (auto it = src.begin(), end = src.end() - (w - 1); it < end; ++it) 
    {
        if (it_min >= it) {
            //if last minimum element is still in the window, we only have to check it against the new addition
            it_min = minIterator(it_min, it + (w - 1));
        } else {
            it_min = std::min_element(it, it + w );
        }           
        res.push_back(*it_min);         
    }   
}
```

I personally would also change the interface to:

```
template<class C>
std::vector<typename C::value_type> GetMinLookUpForWindow(C src, const size_t w)
```

or (more STL-like)

```
template<class IT_IN, class IT_OUT >
void GetMinLookUpForWindow(IT_IN start, IT_IN end, IT_OUT res, const size_t w)
```

The problem with most algorithms you mentioned, like `std::copy_if` or `std::transform` is, that they work on a per element basis and don't give you easy access to the surrounding elements. So avoiding a loop altogether would probably lead to less readable and more error prone code.

Comment: thanks for showing this simplistic way, I was unnecessary wasting my energies in wrong directions.

Comment: @VivekS: Well, my solution is indeed much simpler than yours, but keep in mind, that it is also not the most efficient one. Especially for large windows, it might be beneficial to keep a little more state around  (as you did). However, as a rule of thumb, I only spend time on optimizing my algorithms, if a) they are used in a time-critical piece of code or a library and b) if I have a representative benchmark to show that the more complex version is also faster.

Comment: yes you right, initial thought was the efficiency only which got a hit with a simpler solution, even i was working on it to get done in both simple and efficient way, you did some part but am still working :)